# Making graphs, still new to coding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate 538's daily show graph. https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/every-guest-jon-stewart-ever-had-on-the-daily-show/

I only got the y axis so far, I am stuck on the x axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x = linspace(0,10);
xticks([0, 5, 10])
xticklabels({'x = 0','x = 5','x = 10'})


#date = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]

#N = 5

#ind = np.arange(N)

#plt.xticks((ind, '2000', '04', '08', '12'))

#plt.xticks(["2000", "'04", "'08", "'12"])

#years = mdates.YearLocator()

#yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)

#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)

#ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

#ax.grid(True)
```

I showed 3 different ways to address the problem. For the uncommented code, I got this error message: `name 'linspace' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the [numpy documentation online](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), the *linspace* method is part of the numpy package.

This means that you need to reference the numpy package if you want to use it: you've already imported it as numpy (`import numpy as np`), but you must now write `x = np.linspace(0, 10);` instead of merely `x = linspace(0, 10);`, as you did with other members of the numpy package.

Otherwise, *linspace* is undefined as far as the Python interpreter is concerned.